# recyclerview get item clicked value and open activity - apk crashes

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview to show list itens like this:

```
Image.jpg
Name: josh
Publisher: 1999

Image2.jpg
Name: marie
Publisher: 2002

...
```

I'd like, when user click in josh or marie (name) it calls Profile.java using intent and put its content, the name, to next activity, so I know which profile should be opened. (if user click in marie, put marie to next activity)

The problem is when I click in josh, marie... the app crashes.

What is wrong?

```
//Initializing Views
public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    imageView = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewHero);
    textViewName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
    textViewPublisher = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewPublisher);
    textViewName.setClickable(true);
    textViewName.setOnClickListener(this);
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    final Intent intent;
    intent =  new Intent(context, Profile.class);
    intent.putExtra("user", R.id.textViewName);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Thank you friends.

my profile:

```
package com.sl.meetf;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Profile extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String user = intent.getStringExtra("user");

        String message = user + " welcome to user area";

        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();

    }
}
```

Comment: please post the error log

Comment: U cannot use pass R.id.textViewName in putExtralike this

Comment: pls share "Profile" activity code..

Comment: Post your error log first. Check your `context` must not be `null`. Instead of passing `R.id.textViewName` as a value pass it by `txtview.getText().toString()`

Comment: @RichJoe please check my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this

```
intent =  new Intent(context, Profile.class);
    intent.putExtra("user", R.id.textViewName);
    context.startActivity(intent);
```

with

```
intent =  new Intent(context, Profile.class);
    intent.putExtra("user", textViewName.getText().toString());
    context.startActivity(intent);
```

hope it helps

EDIT:

try this if onClick cant work for you

```
textViewName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               intent =  new Intent(context, Profile.class);
               intent.putExtra("user", textViewName.getText().toString());
               context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

And please check your profile.class not contains any error or share logcat

Comment: If this helps you please mark this as a correct answer so other getting help from this

Comment: welcome bro. If any problem still there feel free to ask, Happy to help you :) :) .And if this helps mark this as a correct answer so other getting help from this

Comment: it's still crashing :/ the `textViewName.setClickable(true);` is correct?

Comment: yes thats correct. If this cant work please try my updated answer

Comment: please cehck my edited answer. If this wont work please share your logcat and check profile.class activity

Comment: thank you very much, friend! I think the problem now is in my Profile.class. because I changed to another class the intent and it works nice! I uploaded my answer with my profile.java code, I really appreciate if you could help me with it too! thank you again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136151/discussion-between-zaki-pathan-and-rick-joe).

Answer (score 1):

you need to get name from the textviewName not resource id .
For example

```
  @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
        final Intent intent;
        intent =  new Intent(context, Profile.class);
        intent.putExtra("user",textviewName.getText().toString());
        context.startActivity(intent);
  }
```